# What does $n$ represent in "hydrated compound⋅nH2O"?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, water, notation

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrate?oldformat=true) it is written that in "hydrated compound⋅nH2O" $n$ is the number of water molecules per formula unit of the salt. I don't understand what that means and this is indicated in that I can't express it in other terms for being able to express a statement in other terms is a sign of understanding it. Can you express this in other terms? How do you imagine these n water molecules to be arranged in a formula unit?

Comment: It is the encyklopedia Wikipedia based  on wiki technology, with Wikiwand taking Wikipedia content and rewriting it for Wikiwand GUI. Wikiwand pages usually contain all sorts of 3rd party elements.

Comment: OrangeApple2 . n Plums means that for each orange and 2 apples, there is n plums, *regardless of* how oranges, apples and plums are mutually arranged in the sack.

Comment: @Poutnik I can now express it in other terms as well; $n$ represents the same thing that any other subscript number represents in the formula of any ionic compound ie the corresponding number obtained in finding the simplest whole-number ratio of the number of atoms in any of its crystal.

Comment: @Poutnik You may post it as answer so that I can close this post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to understand this form of writing the solution: (some salt • n H₂O)?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-to-understand-this-form-of-writing-the-solution-some-salt-n-h%e2%82%82o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OrangeApple2 . n Plums means that for each orange and 2 apples, there is n plums, regardless of how oranges, apples and plums are mutually arranged in the sack.*

Now more seriously:
When there is a chemical formula like $\ce{AB2. n H2O}$, then it means there is substance  $\ce{AB2}$ (ionic like $\ce{A^2+}$ + $\ce{2 B-}$, molecular like $\ce{B-A-B}$ or large scale bound with A:B ratio 1:2), which incorporates in its solid structure (crystals, microcrystalic, amorphous) molecules of water in ratio 1 $\ce{AB2}$ : $\ce{n H2O}$.

Usually, such $\ce{AB2}$ can exist as anhydrate ( being anhydrous) too, without water (like there is anhydrous citric acid and its monohydrate).

Some substances can exist in several variants with different values of $n$. E.g. [calcium chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_chloride) $\ce{CaCl2}$ can be anhydrous (n=0),monohydrate(1), dihydrate(2), tetrahydrate(4), hexahydrate(6).

The formula gives generally nothing more nor less than the stoichiometric substance : water ratio, without any hint about the particular structure and molecular/atomic/ionic placement. In a case of salts, some water molecules wrap cations similarly as in solution, some may be independent or attached to anions.